# Simplify expression involving fractions for mathematical induction proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I have this expression

$1-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$

that I need to manipulate into looking like

$1-\frac{1}{k+2}$

as the final step in my mathematical induction proof process.

My idea was to go something like this:
\begin{align*}
1-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} &= 1-\frac{k+2}{(k+1)(k+2)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
                                   &= 1-\frac{(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\\
                                   &= 1-\frac{(k+2)+1}{(k+1)(k+2)} \cdot \frac{k+1}{k+2}\\
                                   &= 1-\frac{1}{k+2}
\end{align*}
Is this algebraically correct?

Comment: Dos $k+1(k+2)$ mean $2k+2$ or $k^2+3k+2$?

Answer (score 2):

The first part is right, but:

$$1-\frac{k+2}{(k+1)(k+2)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
$$= 1 - \left(\frac{k+2}{(k+1)(k+2)} -\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} \right)$$
$$= 1 - \frac{k+2 \color{red}{-} 1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$

and you can continue from here.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help.